# Laravel-mix-criticalcss in Docker cannot read property 'content-type'

Tags: laravel, docker, critical-css

I'm trying to set up [laravel-mix-criticalcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-criticalcss) in a Docker container and I'm getting an error. Has anyone come across this before?

**Error**

> [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of
> undefined
> at temp (/var/www/html/node_modules/critical/lib/file-helper.js:112:37)
> at /var/www/html/node_modules/critical/lib/file-helper.js:214:27
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> error Command failed with exit code 2.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-criticalcss');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.bundle.scss', 'public/build/css')
    .criticalCss({
    enabled: mix.inProduction(),
    paths: {
        base: 'http://localhost',
        templates: './',
        suffix: '_critical.min'
    },
    urls: [
        { url: '', template: '/' },
    ],
    options: {
        minify: true,
    },
});
```

[image: docker ps]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined
    at temp (/var/www/skin.test/node_modules/html-critical-webpack-plugin/node_modules/critical/lib/file-helper.js:107:37)
    at /var/www/skin.test/node_modules/html-critical-webpack-plugin/node_modules/critical/lib/file-helper.js:205:27
```

and what I found:

[https://github.com/addyosmani/critical/issues/414](https://github.com/michtio/laravel-mix-criticalcss/issues/11)

[https://github.com/michtio/laravel-mix-criticalcss/issues/11](https://github.com/ampedweb/laravel-mix-criticalcss)

so, the problem was `html-critical-webpack-plugin` that used old `critical` version

I reinstalled `laravel-mix-criticalcss` from @ampedweb fork:
https://github.com/ampedweb/laravel-mix-criticalcss

Then I passed production url to plugin's settings `pathes.base` to check if critical css worked.

I got new error - `Error: Failed to launch the browser process!`

I found a troubleshooting url here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md.

Then I installed all recommended libraries from URL above to node container, and now critical CSS works at least for production.

Now I try to figure out with local critical CSS in Docker (I have local error `RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`).